# how to convert binary heap sort to d_ary heap sort?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, heap

Hi I have an algorithm that uses binary tree to heapify and then sort the list i need to convert this sort algorithm to change into d-heap or d-ary heap or k-ary heap
my code is here

```
def build_heap(lista, num):
    """Function to construct heap."""
    for i in range(num // 2 - 1, -1, -1):
        heapify(lista, num, i)


def heapify(lista, num, index):
    """Function to heapify list."""
    largest = index
    left = (2 * index) + 1
    right = (2 * index) + 2

    if left < num and lista[largest] < lista[left]:
        largest = left

    if right < num and lista[largest] < lista[right]:
        largest = right

    if largest != index:
        lista[index], lista[largest] = lista[largest], lista[index]
        heapify(lista, num, largest)


def heapsort(lista,d=2):
    """Function for final Heap sort."""
    length = len(lista)
    build_heap(lista, length)

    for i in range(length - 1, 0, -1):
        lista[i], lista[0] = lista[0], lista[i]
        heapify(lista, i, 0)
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

Add the `d` parameter to all your functions, and generalise. The formula for where to start the heapify function is `(num + 1) // d - 1`. Where you have `left` and `right` indices and choose the one that has the greatest value, instead iterate the children in a `for` loop to find the child with the greatest value.

```
def build_heap(lista, d, num):
    for i in range((num + 1) // d - 1, -1, -1):
        heapify(lista, d, num, i)


def heapify(lista, d, num, index):
    largest = index
    for child in range(d * index + 1, min(num, d * index + d + 1)):
        if lista[largest] < lista[child]:
            largest = child

    if largest != index:
        lista[index], lista[largest] = lista[largest], lista[index]
        heapify(lista, d, num, largest)


def heapsort(lista, d=2):
    length = len(lista)
    build_heap(lista, d, length)

    for i in range(length - 1, 0, -1):
        lista[i], lista[0] = lista[0], lista[i]
        heapify(lista, d, i, 0)
```

Comment: not working it makes error

Comment: See it run without error on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcoma722223635459839#main.py).

Comment: Did you check? If you still have a problem, can you provide the input for which you have a problem? You asked *"please help"*, but I cannot help if you don't come back to me.